# Adding outlet to 4-way light switch circuit

Tags: wiring

I have a 4-way light circuit that I'd like to add an outlet to.  It's a light-first circuit, with no neutral in the switch boxes, as in this picture.

[image: 4-way circuit]

Is the only way to do that to splice the /2 at the input to the fixture and run /2 to the receptacle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's the only way to do it. You need an always hot and a neutral and the fixture is the only place where you can get them. You would pigtail the black and white  wire at the yellow wire nut and pigtail the white neutral before it connects to the light. Are you sure there's not another circuit or outlet that you could feed your new outlet from? Also, the white wire at the fixture and into the first box from the fixture should be taped with any color but green, or white, to indicate an always hot feed. Black is a good color since most people have black electrical tape. It's also a good idea to tape the travelers with yellow tape for easy identification in the future.

Comment: Thanks; that's what I was afraid of.  Unfortunately, it's by far the closest circuit to where I need another source/outlet.  None of the white wires that are hot are taped in this house - the wiring was done in the early 1970s (when the house was built), when it wasn't strictly code, I gather.  It's rather annoying.  I fix them up as I run across them.

Answer (score 1):

Jack has the answer.

The only other conceivable option is in the smart-switch world.  You could re-task all the blacks to be always-hot and all the whites to be **neutral**.  Now you have 120V bussed down the entire switch chain.   Fit a smart bulb in the light socket. Then, fit smart switches at all locations that are capable of powerline or wireless communication (e.g. Insteon) to the bulb. The red wire is unused.

Comment: Wouldn't  you need a neutral for the smart switches?  I "taped" those travelers just for you. stay safe out there.+

Comment: @JACK Oh you're right Jack, I bodged up that answer.  Too late at night lol.

Comment: Typing this stuff out is harder than doing the work.